# Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hadoop in Maven for Oozie installation

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

i am trying to configure Oozie-4.0.1 with JDK 1.7, Hadoop-2.2.0 and Ubuntu, Maven 3. But i am getting following error:

```
1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [1.193s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [37.200s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [4.551s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [0.248s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [0.682s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [3.693s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [0.808s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [0.227s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ............ SUCCESS [2.579s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 Test ....... SUCCESS [1:23.795s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ..... SUCCESS [1.773s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [11.111s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [37.207s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ........................... SUCCESS [0.610s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1 ........... SUCCESS [2:03.191s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.6.0.oozie-4.0.1 ........... SUCCESS [26.185s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ........................ SUCCESS [0.884s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... FAILURE [18.947s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5:56.548s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Feb 01 14:17:19 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.2.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.2.0.oozie-4.0.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.2.0.oozie-4.0.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-sharelib-oozie

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

I am using this link : [http://ngsda.blogspot.in/2014/10/install-oozie-on-ubuntu-1404-with.html](http://link). but getting above error on `bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -Dhadoopversion=2.2.0  -DjavaVersion=1.7 -DtargetJavaVersion=1.7`

Answer (score 0):

have you update with the hadoop version in the pom.xml, as per the shared mail the instruction is not updated with the POM.XML.
These is required as in default Oozie builds against Hadoop 1.1.1, so to build against Hadoop 2.4.1, we will have to configure maven dependencies in pom.xml

for reference you can check with Gaurav's Instalation Instruction to update th.
URL e version of ur node:

```
http://gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/
```